# button onClick listener. Not entering in onClick function

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

In my android application I'm changing button image for 1 sec. There is group of buttons. In that 1 sec image of any one button is get changed. If in that 1 sec I click on that particular button I want to perform some operation.using onclick listener i tried but it's not working. How can I do this? Please help me below is the code-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.next);

myTimer = new Timer();

myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {  

@Override
public void run() {
  if(time==-1){

    onStop();
  }
  else
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

      Random rand=new Random();               
      time=time-1;
      but1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
      but1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.happy);
      but1.setContentDescription("happy");
      but2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
      but2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.happy);
      but2.setContentDescription("happy");

      int num = rand.nextInt(buttonIds.length);
      int buttonId = buttonIds[num];

      Button bb=(Button) findViewById(buttonId);

      if(bb.getContentDescription().equals(button.getContentDescription()))
      {
        bb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.happy);
        bb.setContentDescription("happy");
        wrong++;
      }
      else
      {
        bb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whoa);
        count++;

        bb.setContentDescription("whoa");
      }

    }
  });
}

},0, 1000);
}

public void onClick(View v){
//when i clicked on any button its not even entering here
System.out.println("in onlcik............");
int aaa=v.getId();
System.out.println("click id is------------"+aaa);
for(i=0;i<9;i++){
if(aaa==buttonIds[i]){
    findViewById(buttonIds[i]).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        Drawable dd=findViewById(buttonIds[i]).getBackground();
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
         System.out.println("yes...");

        }
    });
}
}
}

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to add onClickListener to your buttons.

Try adding

```
 but1.setOnClickListener(this);
    but2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

to your code.

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to call `buttonObj.setOnClickListener(this);` from your code.
i added `this` as you are trying to add `public void onClick(View v)` in your activity it seems. also inherit onClickListner by `implementing` `View.onClickListner` in `yourActivity`.

so you need two changes

```
Class YourActivity extends Activity implements View.onClickListener
```

and

```
buttonObj.setOnClickListener(this); // must be after initializing buttonObject
```